# Create a good looking chat layout with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to arrange some html elements in a way to make a good user interface.
I am using MVC and ASP.NET to create this chat client. But I cannot get get the items arranged  correctly. By default the MVC project in visual studio comes with a strip of items on the top of the webpage and extends all the way across the page. I want to have the textarea at the top left of the page below the default strip with the entire message-dialog div below the text area with the same width as the textarea.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container" id="message-dialog">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
</div>
<div class="container" id="discussion-dialog">
    <textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="discussion"></textarea>
</div>
```

I have got it kind of setup once but when i changed the the size of the page all the divs were overlapping and was just a mess.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks though!

Comment: Show us how you figured it out or remove your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
#discussion-dialog 
{
    border: 3px solid #cccccc;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

#message-line {
    position: relative;
}

#message-dialog
{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```